# This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided :: nested object, Typescript, React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, react-typescript, react-state

I have trying state manipulations of react in typescript. I have defined user object and interface of nested object. I am getting error while rendering nested object of user.

```
type gender = "male" | "female";
interface socialAccountsType{
    [accounts: string]:string | any,
    educationSocials?:any
}
interface User{
    name:string,
    address:string,
    gender:gender,
    socials:socialAccountsType
}
const Myuser: User ={
    "name":"liveeverymoment",
    "gender":"male",
    "address":"abcd",
    "socials":{"linkedin":"https://mylinkedin.com","educationSocials":{"ieee":"https://myieee.com"}}
}
const [personBio,setPersonBio] = useState(Myuser)


return(
<p>
    Name: {personBio.name}<br/>
    Gender: {personBio.gender}<br/>
    Address:  {personBio.address}<br/>
    Socials:
            <ul>
                    {Object.entries(personBio.socials || {}).map(([key,value])=>
                    <li key={key}>
                        {key}:{key==='educationSocials'?Object.entries(value || {}).map(([subKey,subValue])=><li key={subKey}>{subKey}:{subValue}</li>):value}
                    </li>
                    )}
            </ul>
</p>
```

Error occurs for {subValue}:

***This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided.***

I have tried using {} with return statement, but same error was given. while {} with return statement, i can console log the nested objects values, but can not render it in UI.

```
Socials:<ul>
           {Object.entries(personBio.socials || {}).map(([key,value])=>{
               if(key!=='educationSocials'){
                   return(<li key={key}>{key}:{value}</li>)
               }else{
                   Object.entries(value || {}).map(([subKey,subValue])=>{
                   console.log(subKey,subValue);
                   //return<li key={subKey}>{subKey}:{subValue}</li>
                   })
               return(<li key={1}>1</li>)
               }
            })}</ul>
```